# Calculate StartDate using FirstDayOfWeek and FirstWeekOfYear

Tags: c#, datetime

My StartYear is 2009, `FirstDayOfWeek` is Monday, `FirstWeekOfYear` is First full week.

So as per above criteria in 2009 calendar, 1st week actually start from 5th. 
So how do i get StartDate of year using above conditions (`FirstDayOfWeek` and `FirstWeekOfYear` (Calendar rule))? It should be generic.

Comment: New user, don't just down vote. Explain why to give him a chance to learn.

Comment: What do you mean by "StartDate for the year"? It's the same every year - January 1. Are you looking for the day of the week that January 1 falls on?

Comment: @AnnaLear, StartDate of year need not be 1st Jan. because if you take example of 2009, my criteria are FirstDayOfWeek is monday and FirstWeekOfYEar is FFirst Full week, so now actual week start from 5th of Jan and StartDate is 5th Jan 2009. so a generic method which can calculate this would be nice.

Comment: Ah, so you're looking for the first day of the first week of the year, just as @jgauffin guessed. Cool.

Comment: @AnnaLear, link 'jgauffin' had referred doesn't consider FirstDayOfWeek and Calendar rule. But i need to consider them while calculating first date.

Comment: a very useful (opensource) library for this sort of calculations is NodaTime (see http://code.google.com/p/noda-time/).

Answer (score 0):

Updated the code again.

```
public DateTime GetFirstDayOfFirstWeek(int year, CultureInfo culture)
{
    // calc first date of this week
    var firstDateOfWeek = new DateTime(year, 1, 10);
    while (firstDateOfWeek.DayOfWeek != culture.DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek)
        firstDateOfWeek = firstDateOfWeek.AddDays(-1);

    // get current week number
    int weekNum = culture.Calendar.GetWeekOfYear(firstDateOfWeek, culture.DateTimeFormat.CalendarWeekRule, culture.DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek);

    // remove all weeks except the first one
    return firstDateOfWeek.AddDays(7 - (weekNum * 7));
}

var date = GetFirstDayOfFirstWeek(2009, new CultureInfo("sv-se"));
```

Note to the code: I'm STILL using `CultureInfo` and not taking rules as arguments. By doing this I'm doing you a favor :) You should learn to use the built in Culture features in .NET. It will help you save a lot of time.

(if you still don't want to use the culture, just modify the code)

Comment: I have reused your code, but it is returning me wrong result when i use Calendar rule as Full week and FirstDay of week is monday. For weekNum is returning 52 and firstDayOfFirstWeek is showing wrong value.  Code is in below comment.

Comment: private static void GetFirstDayOfFirstWeek(int year, out DateTime firstDayOfFirstWeek, DayOfWeek firstDayOfWeek1, CalendarWeekRule cwr)
        {
            GregorianCalendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();

            var firstDateOfWeek = new DateTime(year, 1, 1);
            while (firstDateOfWeek.DayOfWeek != firstDayOfWeek1)
                firstDateOfWeek = firstDateOfWeek.AddDays(-1);

            int weekNum = calendar.GetWeekOfYear(firstDateOfWeek, cwr, firstDayOfWeek1);

            firstDayOfFirstWeek = firstDateOfWeek.AddDays(7 - (weekNum * 7));
        }

Comment: you are using it incorrectly. Which kind if input (year, a date or something else) do you want to use to get the date?

Comment: I want to use year, e.g. I call method with below values 

GetFirstDayOfFirstWeek("2009", out DateTime firstDayOfFirstWeek, DayOfWeek.Monday, CalendarWeekRule.FirstFullWeek)